# jQuery-File-Upload не загружает файл чанками в Safari под Windows

Tags: jquery, windows, ios, safari

jQuery-File-Upload в Safari под Windows не делит файл на чанки, а отправляет файл полностью, хотя в документации Desktop browsers - Apple Safari 4.0+, я использую Safari 5.1.7. Не понятна причина такой работы, в остальных браузерах загружает файл чанками.

Код, где устанавливаю размер чанка.

```
$('.fileupload').each(function () {  
      $(this).fileupload({  
                dropZone: $(this),  
                url: 'http://myhost/fileupload/',  
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp4|mov)$/i,  
                maxChunkSize: 10000000,  
                always: function(e, data) {                  
                    console.log(data.textStatus);  
                }  
      });  
});
```

В Safari под iOS обнаружил проблему, загружается первый чанк и браузер перезагружается ввиду неизвестной ошибки - iOS 9.0.2.

Получается под iOS деление на чанки есть, а в Safari под Windows нет. На Mac не проверял ввиду его отсутствия.

Может кто может помочь и уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой !